# Converting perl Data Dumper Format into JSON

Tags: json, perl

I have Dumper outputting data correctly:

```
      'Apps' => [
                            \{
                                'name' => '1'
                              },
                            \{
                                'name' => '2'
                              },
                            \{
                                'name' => '3'
                              },
                            \{
                                'name' => '4'
                              },
                            \{
                                'name' => '5'
                              },
                            \{
                                'name' => '6'
                              },
                            \{
                                'name' => '7'
                              }
                          ],
      'code' => 'SUCCESS'
    };
```

But when I convert it to JSON I have a lot of problems:

```
  my @jsonapps;
  my @apps = map { $_ } keys %glob;
  my %hash;
  $hash{'code'} = 'SUCCESS';

  for (@apps) {
     my $app = { 'name' => $_ };
     push (@jsonapps, \$app);
  }

 # $hash{'Apps'} = \@jsonapps;

  my $jsonfinal = encode_json \%hash;
  print $jsonfinal;
```

It definitely has to do when with I try to add an array of hashes in:

```
$hash{'Apps'} = \@jsonapps;
```

But I'm having a problem doing that since all the hashes have the same key "name". I need my output to look like:

```
{"code":"SUCCESS","Apps":[{"name":"1"},{"name":"2"},{"name":"3"},{"name":"4"},{"name":"5"},{"name":"6"},{"name":"7"}]}
```

Thanks, I appreciate the help - I've scoured everywhere to figure out how to do this, and I'm just banging my head against the wall now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice the extra `\` in your dump output.

```
'Apps' => [
                \{
                    'name' => '1'
                  },
```

This is because it they are references to hash references. The problem code is here:

```
for (@apps) {
    my $app = { 'name' => $_ };
    push (@jsonapps, \$app);
}
```

`$app` is already a hashref since you use braces and assign it to a scalar. But adding the `\` in front when you push it to `@jsonapps` means you are pushing the reference to the hashref. You don't need to make it a reference because it is already a reference. You just need to omit the `\`.

```
for (@apps) {
    my $app = { 'name' => $_ };
    push (@jsonapps, $app);
}
```